# Can't use spaces in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="customScroll">
        <li class="keep-open">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                Вечеринка - Radioactive -
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <div id="description" class="form-control editable"  spellcheck="true" data-medium-element="true" aria-multiline="true" medium-editor-index="0" data-placeholder="Введите ваше описание..." contenteditable="true"></div>
                {{> form}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Stylus

```
li.open
   border 1px solid #e8e8e8
   border-radius 5px
   ul.dropdown-menu
       position relative
       box-shadow none
```

So I'm using meteor, bootstrap dropdowns and medium-editor for this. But if div with contenteditable is inside li.keep-open item spaces will not work and if outside li it works. So how do I make it so spaces would work?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @AustinCollins I rewrote the question

Comment: Dont you have to use an ``<li>`` element in the second (nested) ``<ul>``?

Comment: Yeah that's right but it doesn't helps

Comment: Have a look at this gif. Looks like it's trying to do something. http://gyazo.com/0a6121545a2f98209e40578163626a78

Comment: Invalid HTML is going to cause things to not work. A div can not be a child of an ul.

Comment: but how do I fix it?

Comment: @Revels did you ever figure out what the problem was? I'm having a similar issue. Spaces don't do anything, but if I type a `*` then spaces start working.

Comment: @Revels I have a similar issue where spacebars do not work in contenteditable. Did you figure out why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your libraries. I tracked my issue to a catch by a library that I was using: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/422

Comment: How did you manage to narrow it down to a single package? I am also debugging this issue; any debugging tips?

Comment: @SungWonCho I removed libraries one by one until it worked. A real pain, but I don't really know of a better way. If it were easier, developers wouldn't be compensated so well.